# Почему возникает ошибка при сборке?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, npm, сборка

Впервые пытаюсь использовать webpack. Пишу `webpack -w` и мне кидает ошибку:

```
$ webpack -w

webpack is watching the files…



#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Check failed: U_SUCCESS(status).
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0000005154EFD760
```

Проект не мой и там уже был конфиг для вебпака:

```
let path = require('path');
let MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
let conf = {
    entry: './web/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './web/dist'),
        filename: 'main.js',
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    },
    devServer: {
        overlay: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: '/node_modules/',
            },
            {
                // Fonts
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: "file-loader",
                options: {
                  name: "[name].[ext]"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(s*)css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                     MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {sourceMap:true}
                    }, {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {sourceMap:true, config:{path: 'config/postcss.config.js'}}
                    }, {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {sourceMap:true}
                    },
                ],
                // exclude: '/node_modules/',
            }
        ],
    },
};

module.exports = conf;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, проблема исправится, если собирать на ноде 10 версии.

Comment: А как ее откатить?

Comment: Если вы на винде, например, установите nvm.
В целом, все можно найти на просторах интернета - так оно даже лучше запоминается на будущее)

[https://proweb63.ru/help/js/nvm-windows](https://proweb63.ru/help/js/nvm-windows)